# In App Purchase Review Screenshot says wrong size

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to create a non-consumable in app purchase for my app. The requirements say that for an iOS project your screenshot needs to be at least 640x920. I took a screenshot from the simulator which is larger than that size. I still get an error about using a proper size.
I did crop it to 640x920 just to be sure, still not working.

This is the error I'm getting

[image]

Does anybody else have this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The solution to the problem is to use Safari instead of Chrome or whatever browser you are using AND to scale the photo to exactly 640x920 for an iOS app. This is probably a bug in the iTunes Connect website.

Comment: Funny though, as of April 2020 this bug is still bothering us and Apple hasn't even updated its documentation (it still says "at least")

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, for subscriptions I only had success uploading a screenshot in 2048x1536.

Answer (score 0):

Try run it on the simulator and using `Command + S` to take screenshot~
In my case i am using a device with 750 * 1334 resolution to take screenshot.

Comment: That is what I did. With a 7 plus simulator. 931x1656 to be exact is the resulting screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Safari and exactly 920x640 in dimension.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).